# Assign the count of every element of an array to each element of another array without count()

Tags: c++, arrays

Basically I have two int arrays, S[N], which contains N instances of M elements, and which may or may not contain duplicates, and Sr[M], which I want to fill with the amount of instances of every element of S[N]. For example, if the input were:

```
10 5
1 2 3 4 1 5 1 5 2 1
```

then N = 10, M = 5,

```
S[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 2, 1 }

Sr[5] = { 4, 2, 1, 1, 2 } // 4 instances of the number 1, 2 instances of the number 2, 1 instance of the number 3 and so on.
```

So far I have used this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int N, M;

ifstream input;
input.open("aris.in");
input >> N >> M;

int S[N], Sr[M];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    input >> S[i];
}
input.close();

for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
    Sr[i] = count(S, S+N, i+1);
}

return 0;
}
```

How can I get the same result without using the count() function from the algorithm library?

Comment: You can program your own `count()` function...

Comment: What if there are missing numbers in `S`?  Example: `1 2 3 7 8 9` -- 4, 5, 6 are missing.  If there can be missing numbers, what should `Sr` array look like?  And if this is the case, what if the gap between missing numbers is large, say `1, 2, 1000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all varaible length arrays are not supported in C++. So you have either to allocate dynamically the arrays or to use standard container `std::vector`.

Whatever container you will use the loop can look the following way

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
    ++Sr[S[i]-1];
}
```

Of course initially each element of `Sr`  must be set to 0.

Also I suppose that values of `S` start from 1.